# What is the timeframe of the Yerkes–Dodson law?

Tags: stress

What is the timeframe of the Yerkes–Dodson law?

The Yerkes–Dodson law is defined this way ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerkes%E2%80%93Dodson_law)):

> The Yerkes–Dodson law is an empirical relationship between pressure and performance, originally developed by psychologists Robert M. Yerkes and John Dillingham Dodson in 1908.1 The law dictates that performance increases with physiological or mental arousal, but only up to a point. When levels of arousal become too high, performance decreases.

I am not sure what is the timeframe for this experienced stress. Is it true for a stress which lasts several (dozens) of minutes, or several days?